# CENT-OS ssh still asking for password after copying public key to authorized_keys

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, authentication

debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55b9fa275e80)
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for host1-1.example.com [192.168.5.60] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@192.168.5.60's password:

---

I already have used ssh-copy-id and have restarted the sshd service.

Please help.

Comment: What client are you trying from, Windows? I've used these instructions to setup key-based auth from Windows (client) to CentOS (host): https://www.linode.com/docs/security/authentication/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh/#windows

Comment: Have you tried disabling selinux (temporarily).   That is a common culprit.

Comment: It's from CentoOS to CentOS @SamAndrew81